# Knowing Domain Controller from Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is there a way to know the Domain Controller used by Sharepoint instance? I'm using Sharepoint 2007

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything in the product that directly tells you this.  However as the product defers to IIS/operating system for authentication, you could use any OS tools that you know about to watch what a server is doing with respect to talking to domain controllers.